# FIR Filter length Upper Bound

Tags: filters, filter-design

Say I want to design a low pass filter with stop and pass band ripple constrained to $\epsilon$ and transition region $\delta$, what is the smallest FIR Filter length that suffices? Can you please provide a derivation?

Comment: Is this a homework question? Have you tried looking for a solution?

Comment: I'm not sure why people have voted to close this question as being unclear. I think it's very clear and also very practical. There's even a Matlab function (firpmord.m) that addresses this question by computing an estimate of the required filter order given the filter specification.

Answer (score 4):

Many people have asked themselves this question. Unfortunately, there is no exact solution, just approximations. One relevant paper is [Practical Design Rules for Optimum Finite Impulse Response Low-Pass Digital Filters](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/j.1538-7305.1973.tb01990.x/abstract) by Herrmann, Rabiner and Chan, where they basically fit a formula to their data obtained from lots of designs. A simplified formula is [1]

$$M=\frac{-10\log_{10}(\delta_1\delta_2)-13}{2.324\;\Delta\omega}$$

where $M$ is the filter order, and $\Delta\omega=\omega_s-\omega_p$ is the width of the transition band.

Also the Matlab function `firpmord.m` uses some formula to estimate the necessary filter order, but they also say that the required order is often underestimated.

[1] *Discrete-Time Signal Processing*, Oppenheim, Schafer, Buck (2nd ed.), p. 502

Answer (score -1):

Try the `FDAtool` in MATLAB to experiment with various possible solutions.